Array-union not reduced
Typescript usually reduces types if it can:
type I = string | 'literal';  // => string

type II = number | 0;         // => number

So why is it that it does not reduce array unions:
type I = (1 | 2)[] | number[];     // => number[] | (1 | 2)[]      => Expected: number[]

type II = string[] | 'literal'[];  // =>  string[] | 'literal'[]   => Expected: string[]

Why doesn't TypeScript collapse the type into its supertype.

TS doesn't usually reduce types "if it can", so much as it does so in specific circumstances. TS doesn't automatically reduce object types just because the properties can be reduced, nor does it propagate unions down to properties, (e.g., {x: 1} | {x: 2} doesn't become {x: 1 | 2}, and {x: 1} | {x: number} doesn't become {x: number}). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer with sources; if not, what's missing?

I found this:
type MergeSubtypes<T, U = T> = T extends U
  ? Exclude<U, T> extends infer Rest
    ? T extends Rest
      ? never
      : T
    : never
  : never;

And it does seem to work, but maybe someone can still explain the core reason.

Note that this now does not address the question, so you might want to remove it.
